# Angular conditional components from a common source

Tags: angular, typescript, single-page-application, angular-components

First off, I'd like to mention I'm not an angular developer, almost all my skillset belongs in backend work, but I'm trying to get this concept worked out, and I don't even know if it's possible.  Googling is not much help because I don't even know how to properly phrase the question, so I'm hoping to describe the situation, what I'd like to do, how I'd like it to work, and hopefully get some advice on what I'm trying to do is actually called in the Angular world, whether it's possible, and assuming it's possible, an example of what it would look like.

We have a SPA that has a .NET Core Web API backend.  There is an API endpoint, `/api/feedItems`, that returns a list of "feed items", the rough equivalent of event logs.

The basic shape of a feed item resembles this:

```
export enum FeedItemType {
    undefined = "undefined",
    foo = "foo",
    bar = "bar"
}

export class FeedItemModel {
    id: number;
    createdUtcTimestamp: Date;
    feedType: FeedItemType;
    feedData: {} // object? any?
}
```

The idea here is, all feed items will have certain metadata, including an id, timestamp, feed type identifier, and a payload.  The actual payload contents will be different based upon the `FeedItemType`.

An example feed item list returning from the API call might resemble something like this:

```
[  
    {  
    "id":12345,
    "createdUtcTimestamp":"2018-12-05T13:30:00Z",
    "feedType":"foo",
    "feedData":{  
        "name":"this is a foo type feed",
        "description":"This foo feed is describing an event of type 'foo'"
    }
    },
    {  
    "id":67890,
    "createdUtcTimestamp":"2018-12-06T15:45:00Z",
    "feedType":"bar",
    "feedData":{  
        "value1":11111,
        "value2":22222,
        "value3":33333
    }
    }
]
```

We actually have a lot of different feed item types, and each one should have its own custom rendering to visualize the data in the most useful way.

What I want to do is have an angular component that is responsible for fetching the feed item list from the API and looping through the feed items.  For each feed item (presumably in an `*ngFor` directive), it should render the common properties, then, based upon the `feedType`, render a different "sub" component.

In this case, let's say my container component looks like this:

```
<div class="feed-item-container" *ngFor="let feedItem of feedItemList; let i = index;">
    <div class="feed-item">
        <div class="timestamp-display">{{feedItem.createdUtcTimestamp}}</div>

        <!-- equivalent of "if feedItem.feedType == 'foo'", 
        possibly ngIf or ngSwitch, but I'd prefer to not 
        have to explicitly check for each type -->
        <feed-item-foo (I have no idea how to pass the feedData to this component) />

        <!-- equivalent of "if feedItem.feedType == 'bar'" -->
        <feed-item-bar (again, this is a mystery what should go here) />

        <!-- equivalent of "if can't match on feedType" -->
        <feed-item-generic (something) />
    </div>
</div>
```

The idea here is that I could create components outside of this file, as needed, without making many changes (preferably none) to the container template.  It would be ideal if I could programmatically recognize the `feedType`, look for a registered component selector for it, and pass the `feedData` to it automagically, but if I have to manually reference each component in this container, that's ok too.  I just don't want to put all the rendering logic in this container, as that would very quickly become unwieldy and difficult to manage.

The feed item components will have their own formatting based upon the feed type, with different styling as well, and perhaps different logical operations.  I don't want a giant feedItem container component.

So, is this possible?  If so, how would I go about it?

Comment: No matter now you do it, you'll need _some_ `switch` or `if/else` chain _somewhere_.  A generic `feed-item` component which only decides a concrete `feed-item` to render is a perfectly fine solution, has no impact on performance and is trivial to understand. To pass in data, use a regular input: `<feed-item-foo [foo]="feedItem">`. Give it a proper type information in the `FeedItemFooComponent` itself, such as `@Input() foo: FeedItemFoo`, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i could understand correctly maybe the following idea can help you out..
I take your example and modify it a bit.

```
<div class="feed-item-container" *ngFor="let feedItem of feedItemList; let i = index;">
<div class="feed-item">
    <div class="timestamp-display">{{feedItem.createdUtcTimestamp}}</div>

    <!-- equivalent of "if feedItem.feedType == 'foo'", 
    possibly ngIf or ngSwitch, but I'd prefer to not 
    have to explicitly check for each type -->

    <!-- i do not know of any alternative, but to make it a bit more readable
    you can use <ng-container>

    <ng-container *ngIf="feedItem.feedType === 'foo'">
        <!-- you can create your own component and add an @Input() data, so your component will know what it is dealing with (see example below)
        <feed-item-foo [data]="feedItem"/>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- equivalent of "if feedItem.feedType == 'bar'" -->
    <ng-container *ngIf="feedItem.feedType === 'bar'">
        <!-- you can create your own component and add an @Input() data, so 
        your component will know what it is dealing with (see example below)
        <feed-item-bar [data]="feedItem"/>
    </ng-container>
    <!-- equivalent of "if can't match on feedType" -->
    <!-- that is a bit of a pain in the ... --> 
   <ng-container *ngIf='!foo && !bar && !xyz'>
    <feed-item-generic (something) />
   </ng-container>

</div>
```

Your components can and should all include something like a 'base' class

```
export class FeedItemBase implements OnInit {
  @Input() data = <YourType>null; // that is a little hack to get the type 
  // correct (was some bug in a angular 4 version as far as i remember)
  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    // if needed .. if not, delete it :)
  }
}
```

then all your other classes can extend the base class (since data will always be the same ...

```
export class FeedItemFoo extends FeedItemBase implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    // here you can access data already 
  }
}
```

if you only have 2 types (which i doubt) you could also do something like that:

```
<div class="feed-item-container" *ngFor="let feedItem of feedItemList; let i = index;">
<div class="feed-item">
    <div class="timestamp-display">{{feedItem.createdUtcTimestamp}}</div>

    <!-- equivalent of "if feedItem.feedType == 'foo'", 
    possibly ngIf or ngSwitch, but I'd prefer to not 
    have to explicitly check for each type -->

    <!-- i do not know of any alternative, but to make it a bit more readable
    you can use <ng-template>
    <ng-container *ngIf="feedItem.feedType === 'foo'; then fooId;else barId"> 
    </ng-container>

   <ng-template #fooId>
        <!-- you can create your own component and add an @Input() data, so your component will know what it is dealing with (see example below)
        <feed-item-bar [data]="feedItem"/>
    </ng-template>

    <!-- equivalent of "if feedItem.feedType == 'bar'" -->
    <ng-template #barId>
        <!-- you can create your own component and add an @Input() data, so 
        your component will know what it is dealing with (see example below)
        <feed-item-foo [data]="feedItem"/>
    </ng-container>
    <!-- equivalent of "if can't match on feedType" -->
    <!-- that is a bit of a pain in the ... --> 
   <ng-container *ngIf='!foo && !bar && !xyz'>
    <feed-item-generic (something) />
   </ng-container>

</div>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: It does help, thanks.  Between this and @Lazar's comment, I think I have a decent understanding of what to do.